# Defining a global variable in Cypress that can be used in all test files without creating a new one everytime

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am very desperately looking for a solution to define a global variable and access it everything in all my test files. This is my commands.js. Here i am generating a random mobile number using faker.js. I am doing APIs automated testing but the APIs are executed in a sequence which means there should be one mobile number and one user ID that should be used throughout the test execution.

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
Cypress.Commands.add('generateAndSetMobileNumber', () => {
  // Check if the mobile number is already set in the Cypress environment
  if (!Cypress.env('mobileNumber')) {
    const mobileNumber = faker.datatype.number({ min: 5700000000, max: 5899999999 });
    Cypress.env('mobileNumber', mobileNumber.toString());
  }
});

Cypress.Commands.add('createUser', () => {
  cy.generateRandomMobileNumber().then((mobileNumber) => {

    return cy.api({
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/products/users/',
      body: {
        "countryCode": "971",
        "mobileNo": mobileNumber,
        "viewId": "createView",
        "agentCode": "",
        "language": "EN",
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(201);
      Cypress.env('prospectId', response.body.userId);
    });
  });
});
```

Now these commands are defined here and are working perfectly fine but when I use it in my test classes everything generates a new mobile number and new userID whereas I want one UserID and mobileNumber that can be used throughout the execution.

This is my test file

```
describe("Generating OTP", () => {
before(() => {
 cy.createUser() => {
     
    });
  it("Verify user is able to generate OTP by entering their mobile number", () => {
               UserId = Cypress.env('UserId');
               mobileNumber = Cypress.env('mobileNumber');


    cy.api({
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'products/otp',
      body: {
        "action": "generate",
        "prospectId": prospectId,
        "countryCode": "971",
        "mobileNo": mobileNumber,
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      // Assert that the OTP was generated successfully
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
      expect(prospectId).to.have.length(5);
      // Assert that the OTP is valid
      expect(response.body.verified).to.eq(true);
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried multiple options as follow, but nothing seems to be working for me:

cypress-localstorage-commands plugin
setLocalStorage
getAllSessionStorage
I look forward to prompt support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code already has checks to see if the mobile exists - `if (!Cypress.env('mobileNumber'))`, which means this env var is cleared at certain points.

Certainly, it is cleared between specs: see [Cypress.env](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env)

> **Scope**
> Environment variables set using `Cypress.env` are only in scope for the **current spec file**.

I guess safest approach is to save to a fixture file, using same check logic.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('generateAndSetMobileNumber', () => {
  cy.fixture('mobile.json').then(data => {
    if (!data.mobileNumber') {
      const mobileNumber = ...generate
      cy.writeFile('/cypress/fixtures/mobile.json', { mobileNumber })
    }
  })
})
```

But if you take the idea to the logical conclusion, why have code to generate the number? Why not just a fixed number in a permanent fixture file?

---

**Note** you can call `cy.fixture()` multiple times without the cost of reading each time, because the command is caching the first read.

You have to keep that in mind if trying to force a re-write, using `cy.readFile()` instead of `cy.fixture()`.

Comment: Thank you responding but this does not answer my question. Even if not mobile number, even the userID is being generated everytime a call is made of Cypress.env.

Comment: Oh, I thought you would be able to grasp the principle - `cy.writeFile('/cypress/fixtures/userid.json', { userId: response.body.userId })` - does it look familiar?